# SQL stored procedure to save SUM and use it inside the same SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is for a project for a university class.

I'm creating an SP that declares a float to save the total price from another table values and uses it to insert and update another table, but the problem is that the `@total` is always NULL. If I take the "SELECT ... SUM" and execute it outside the SP with my values, it works!!

```
CREATE PROC grocery.sp_PagamentoTotalValorVenda
@idVenda INT,
@tipoPagamento INT
AS
    DECLARE @total FLOAT
    DECLARE @idContaCorr INT
    DECLARE @idCliente INT

    SELECT @total=SUM(PROD.PVP)
    FROM grocery.ITEM_VENDA AS IV JOIN grocery.PRODUTO AS PROD ON IV.ID_produto = PROD.ID
    WHERE IV.ID_venda=@idVenda
BEGIN
    SELECT @idContaCorr=CONTCORR.ID,@idCliente=VEN.Nif_cliente
    FROM grocery.VENDA AS VEN JOIN grocery.CONTA_CORRENTE AS CONTCORR ON VEN.Nif_cliente=CONTCORR.Nif_cliente
END
BEGIN
    UPDATE grocery.VENDA
    SET Valor=@total
    WHERE ID=@idVenda
END
IF(@tipoPagamento=3)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO grocery.PAGAMENTO
    (ID_venda,Valor,ID_conta_corr,ID_tipo_pag)
    VALUES
    (@idVenda,@total,@idContaCorr,@tipoPagamento);
    EXEC grocery.sp_InsertOUTContaCorrente @idContaCorr, @total
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO grocery.PAGAMENTO
    (ID_venda,Valor,ID_tipo_pag)
    VALUES
    (@idVenda,@total,@tipoPagamento)
END
GO
```

All the code related to this SP is here [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/xg2GyByU)

Comment: Don't 'fix' the code in the question after you've received an answer.  That makes it hard to tell what the answer is explaining was wrong.  Tweaking indentation is OK; editing the code substantively is not.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the info and the edit!

Answer (score 1):

As written, the `BEGIN` is in the wrong place:

```
CREATE PROC grocery.sp_PagamentoTotalValorVenda (
    @idVenda INT,
    @tipoPagamento INT
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @total FLOAT;
    DECLARE @idContaCorr INT;
    DECLARE @idCliente INT;

    SELECT @total = SUM(PROD.PVP)
    FROM grocery.ITEM_VENDA AS IV JOIN
         grocery.PRODUTO AS PROD
         ON IV.ID_produto = PROD.ID
    WHERE IV.ID_venda = @idVenda;
```

Note: Business applications should almost never use `FLOAT`.  Your data type should be either `MONEY` or `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC`.  These are fixed point types and more accurate when rounding and comparing monetary values.

Comment: Please check the pasteBin link, that BEGIN is for the rest of the code, about the FLOAT thank you, I will search for it and change it! Always learning!

Comment: @DiogoFilipe as the great Gordon Linoff says, the being is wrong

Comment: Already tried that but keeps giving me the same error,

Changed the code in the question

ERROR:
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_PagamentoTotalValorVenda, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 613]
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Valor', table 'db_project_grocery.grocery.PAGAMENTO'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: The value in @total should not be null after the SUM, is it because of the scope? Check the code please, I put everything inside the one BEGIN...END

Comment: @DiogoFilipe . . . If nothing matches the `WHERE` then the value will remain `NULL`.

Comment: ahah sorry, the where is matching the ID but because the table where it is going to sum the values(first rows) have a few records that are not fully filled that was returning null because it didn't had nothing to sum.